# Removing whitespace below/above images in horizontally listed images

Tags: html, css, image, list, whitespace

The below image shows my issue:

[image]

I've found an annoying way to remove this whitespace, which is to treat this as 4 different lists and add elements in a too complicated for-loop, which also locks the ammount of columns to four so adjusting the browser window makes it look bad. It feels like there should be a simple way to do this with css but I just can't find it. Any bright ideas?

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not with css.  This is a classic problem.  Making this four **columns** of images instead of two *rows* of images is the only way to do it without javascript or other manipulation.

Comment: Oh crud :/ Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What about making `display` of images as `inline-block` and giving them some margins.
here is an example using `div`s instead of images
http://jsfiddle.net/Z665c/

Comment: Still the same problem, there's a gap between the first and fourth square, counting squares the same way as I do in my image.